# Object initialization from single DataRow

Tags: c#, linq, object-initialization

To populate a List from a DataTable I typically write a statement like this:

```
List<Foo> foos = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dr =>
    new Foo { Bar = Convert.ToIn32(dr["Bar"]),
              Baz = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Baz"]) }).ToList();
```

**How may I write a similar statement to initialize a single object when I know the DataTable will return just 1 row *like the following pseudo code*:**

```
Foo foo = dt.Rows[0].Select(dr =>
    new Foo { Bar = Convert.ToIn32(dr["Bar"]),
              Baz = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Baz"]) });
```

I would like to write just one statement and want to avoid (if possible) 2 lines like this:

```
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
Foo foo = new Foo { Bar = Convert.ToIn32(dr["Bar"]),
                    Baz = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Baz"]) });
```

I have tried combinations of `Where`, `Select`, `First`, `Single` but cannot hit the nail on the head!

Any answers as ever are appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the origin of the DataRow here? there may be ways to skip the DataRow entirely

Comment: The origin of the DataRow is the result of a SQL Stored Proc that returns a DataTable with one row.

Comment: my point is - a stored proc doesn't *really* return a `DataTable`. That is just data-adapter etc. You can omit the `DataTable` *completely* - you *might* (up to you) want to look at `IDataReader`, or tools like "dapper-dot-net" (which will do all the mapping for you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Foo foo = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dr =>
    new Foo { Bar = Convert.ToIn32(dr["Bar"]),
              Baz = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Baz"]) }).Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you *can* do:

```
Foo foo = new Foo { Bar = Convert.ToIn32(dt.Rows[0]["Bar"]),
                    Baz = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["Baz"]) };
```

... but personally I'd prefer the version with a separate variable for the common expression.

Comment: @NeilKnight: Nope, I just had an extra `)` :)